# Best strategy for OAuth2.0 across browsers and across tabs within the same browser?

Tags: oauth2, active-directory, cross-browser, local-storage

I have developed a login system using OAuth2.0 that is currently working within one tab in one browser. Without diving into the code, the system works by having the user enter their credentials to login, the credentials are sent up to the API (WebAPI2 .Net) from the client (Angular), the user is logged in via Active Directory, and then an access token and refresh token are returned to the client.

I am currently storing these within cookies. When an access token expires, the refresh token is grabbed from the cookie and used to get a new access token. All of this is working within one browser tab. However, we want to allow the user to be logged in to multiple tabs within a browser, and/or multiple browsers at the same time without effecting eachother (like facebook, etc.) Cookies are the wrong solution for storing these tokens because they don't communicate between different tabs, so I did some research and found localStorage which probably solves the between tabs problem.

However, I wanted to get some opinions on best strategy for being logged in across multiple tabs/browsers with the same login using OAuth2. I don't think you can store the tokens in SQL because then the call to the API isn't secure to get the refresh tokens across browsers. Do you create separate tokens in each browser with the same login and then localStorage in each browser to share that browser's token? Or is there a way to share refresh tokens safely across multiple browsers?

Comment: “Cookies are the wrong solution for storing these tokens because they don't communicate between different tabs” – cookies are shared between all tabs of the same browser session. After logging in in one tab, when you open your site in another tab you should already be logged in. If that is not the case, check whether the cookies are sent with the HTTP requests, e.g. with browser developer tools. You might then have material for a question on [so].

Answer (score 1):

Between tabs, use `defineProperty` and `sessionStorage`:

```
Object.defineProperty(sessionStorage, "setItem", { writable: true });
sessionStorage.setItem = function () { /* Login logic */ };
```

Between browsers, use `window.postMessage` to communicate the need redirect to the authorization page:

```
 // If the current window is the 'parent', change the URL by setting location.href
  if (window.top == window.self) {
    window.top.location.href = "/auth/shopify?shop=myshopname";

  // If the current window is the 'child', change the parent's URL with postMessage
  } else {
    message = JSON.stringify({
      message: "Shopify.API.remoteRedirect",
      data: { location: window.location.origin + "/auth/shopify?shop=myshopname" }
    });
    window.parent.postMessage(message, "https://myshopname.myshopify.com");
  }
```

**References**

- [Using postMessage during embedded app authenticate · Shopify/shopify_app Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app/wiki/Using-postMessage-during-embedded-app-authenticate)
- [Authorization for Internet of Things using OAuth 2.0](https://www.slideshare.net/HannesTschofenig/authorization-for-internet-of-things-using-oauth-20)
- [Authentication and Authorization for Constrained Environments (ace) - Documents](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/ace/documents/)
- [Cross-window communication](https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication)
- [GitHub - wingify/across-tabs: Easy communication between cross-origin browser tabs](https://github.com/wingify/across-tabs)
- [Web Reflection: Do You Really Know Object.defineProperty ?](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/10/do-you-really-know-objectdefineproperty.html)
- [Can't spyOn sessionStorage or localStorage methods in Firefox · Issue #299 · jasmine/jasmine · GitHub](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/299)